# How can I see branch names grouped by their commit id

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working on a project with several branches, and I have created multiple branch names for the same commit (to try out specific effects of merge strategies and rebasing).  For example, I have this set of commits, seen on a line taken from a `git log --graph` with a `--pretty=format` applied:

```
| | | * 253701d 2018-08-14 (origin/LAADS-1611, LAADS-1647.premerge, LAADS-1647, LAADS-1611.test, LAADS-1611) LAADS-1647 Disable debugging (may be useful later)
```

I can see that I have 4 local branches all at this commit.

What I'd like to do is see them all grouped together when I do a `git branch --list`.  The best I have so far is this output:

`git branch --list --verbose
  LAADS-1439            2f10b40 LAADS-1596 Change to support module integration
  LAADS-1611            253701d LAADS-1647 Disable debugging (may be useful later)
  LAADS-1611.premerge   e39c749 LAADS-1611 Document dependencies in Build.PL
  LAADS-1611.test       253701d LAADS-1647 Disable debugging (may be useful later)
  LAADS-1613            02885e0 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
  LAADS-1613.rebase.2   307cdc9 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
* LAADS-1613.squashes   307cdc9 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
  LAADS-1613.test       02885e0 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
  LAADS-1647            253701d LAADS-1647 Disable debugging (may be useful later)
  LAADS-1647.checkpoint a97e736 LAADS-1611 Bug Fix: Only resolve symlinks for dirs
  LAADS-1647.premerge   253701d LAADS-1647 Disable debugging (may be useful later)
  master                ac23a63 Merge branch 'nrt' into 'master'`

So I can pick out the concurrent branches with work, but it's not easy.  I could pipe it all to a unix `sort` I suppose, but it seems like something that is likely already built in to Git that I've missed.

How can I see the distinct commits that have (possibly mulitple) branch names?

Comment: In recent Git versions, `git for-each-branch` can be used to re-implement `git branch`, and for-each-branch has sorting options. But Git is intentionally at least partly tool-oriented (e.g., "plumbing" commands), and piping through sort is perfectly reasonable too.

Answer (score 1):

When listing branches in git verions >=2.7 you can sort the results based on any field, including the objectname (sha1) of the commit.

```
git branch --list --verbose --sort objectname
```

In more recent versions (`>=2.13.2`) you can use the format option like you can on `git for-each-branch` directly on `git branch` to customize the output.

If you're using something older, it's probably easier to just pipe it into `cut` and `sort` which will at least get them grouped properly (sorting hex numbers doesn't work well).

```
git branch --list --verbose | cut -b 3- | sort -k2,2
```